# PyCharm не видит chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, chromedriver

Пытаюсь использовать selenium в pyсharm, но он не видит chromedriver. Выводит ошибку

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

Запускаю скрипт с тем же кодом не через Pycharm, а просто из терминала - все работает:

```
(venv) empty@admin-comp:~/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject$ python main.py
/home/empty/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject/main.py:10: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
(venv) empty@admin-comp:~/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject$ ^C
(venv) empty@admin-comp:~/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject$
```

chromedriver скачен и установлен в PATH каталог (даже в 3):

```
(venv) empty@admin-comp:~/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject$ echo $PATH
/home/empty/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

empty@admin-comp:/usr/local/bin$ ls
apt  chromedriver  gnome-help  highlight-mint  mint-sha256sum  msedgedriver  search  yelp
```

chromedriver запускается из терминала из того же venv:

```
(venv) empty@admin-comp:~/PycharmProjects/newseleniumproject$ chromedriver
Starting ChromeDriver 105.0.5195.52 (412c95e518836d8a7d97250d62b29c2ae6a26a85-refs/branch-heads/5195@{#853}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

Но при этом скрипт упорно не хочет работать ни при запуске через терминал в pycharm, ни через run. Под виндой все запустилось, но хочется под linux...

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно указать путь к драйверу, например вот так:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Пробовал, и путь к файлу в /usr/local/bin и закидывал chromedriver в venv и указывал к нему путь. Не помогает.